# How to check all multiple keyword should be present in given text or not

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, unix-text-processing

I am bit stuck with this how do I check all keyword should exist in my text

If any one keyword is not present then it should return me status : 1 or else 0

```
keyword='CAP\|BALL\|BAT\|CRICKET'

echo "HE AS CAP AND LOVE TO PLAY BALL BAT , ITS IS CALLED CRICKET"
```

**My code :**

```
echo "HE AS CAP AND LOVE TO PLAY BALL BAT , ITS IS CALLED CRICKET" | grep -w "$keyword"
echo $?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any version of `awk`.

```
keyword='CAP|BALL|BAT|CRICKET'
echo "HE AS CAP AND LOVE TO PLAY BALL BAT , ITS IS CALLED CRICKET" | 
awk -v key="$keyword" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(key,arr,"|")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    value[arr[i]]
  }
}
{
  count=0
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i in value){
      count++
    }
  }
  if(length(value)==count){
    exit 0
  }
  else{
    exit 1
  }
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
keyword='CAP|BALL|BAT|CRICKET'                ##Creating keyword shell variable with values.
echo " CAP   |  BALL |  BA |  CRICKET    " |  ##Printing values by echo command and sending output to awk command.
awk -v key="$keyword" '                       ##Starting awk program and creating variable key which has value of keyword in it.
BEGIN{                                        ##Starting BEGIN section of this awk program from here.
  num=split(key,arr,"|")                      ##Splitting key into array arr with delimiter of | and num will have total number of elements that will come in array.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                        ##Running for loop till value of num.
    value[arr[i]]                             ##Creating array value with index of value of arr here.
  }
}
{
  count=0                                     ##Setting count to 0 here.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                         ##Traversing through all fields here.
    if($i in value){                          ##Checking if current field is present in value.
      count++                                 ##Increasing count with 1 here.
    }
  }
  if(length(value)==count){                   ##Checking if length of value and count is equal then do following:
    exit 0                                    ##Exit from program with status of 0.
  }
  else{                                       ##if all fields are not coming into variable then:
    exit 1                                    ##Exit from program with status of 1.
  }
}
'
```

Comment: I need status so that I can exit code if does not contain all keyword in my text.

Comment: @kiric8494, ok sure, have changed code accordingly now, kindly take a look and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Will add detailed explanation in sometime or so.

Comment: Not working showing error like : `awk : warning : escape sequence '\|'  treated as plain '|'`

Comment: @kiric8494, its a tested code and working fine for me, what version of `awk` do you have? Do a `awk --version` on your machine? Also which OS you are using.

Comment: @kiric8494, just now saw, you need not to escape | in your shell variable. Make it as `keyword='CAP|BALL|BAT|CRICKET'` and it should fly then. You need not to escape `|` in your shell variable.

Comment: : Any alternate way .. its not working for me  all exact keyword should match.. Just take instead of `BALL` as `BAL` in echo text see it returns status as 0 it should be 1

Comment: @kiric8494, could you please confirm `keyword='CAP|BALL|BAT|CRICKET'` is what you have used and you have copy/pasted exact code shown here? As mentioned its a tested code and its working fine for me, let me know.

Comment: @kiric8494, and yes I have changed from `BALL` to `BAL` and it shown me status `1` on shell terminal.

Comment: sorry my echo text as following data   `echo "  RAJ AS CAP | HE LOVES BAT | BALL IS SUNIL FAVIRITE | LETS PLAY CRICKET  "`

Comment: :  can you try for this `echo "  RAJ AS CAP | HE LOVES BAT | BALL IS SUNIL FAVIRITE | LETS PLAY CRICKET  "`    ... you code will fail to return status as 1

Comment: @kiric8494, it runs fine for me `tmp]# echo $?
0
` it gives me `0` status with your shown samples, it worked fine for me :)

Comment: @kiric8494, I ran exactly: `echo "  RAJ AS CAP | HE LOVES BAT | BALL IS SUNIL FAVIRITE | LETS PLAY CRICKET  " | 
awk -v key="$keyword" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(key,arr,"|")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    value[arr[i]]
  }
}
{
  count=0
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i in value){
      count++
    }
  }
  if(length(value)==count){
    exit 0
  }
  else{
    exit 1
  }
}
'` coming in one liner in comments(don't run it just showing you)

Comment: can you check this one  `echo " CAP   |  BALL |  BA |  CRICKET    "`

Comment: @kiric8494, that's obvious right, there is NO `BAT` in input so it will give `1`, that's a correct use case, its working fine IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to achieve this using `shell` and `grep`:

```bash
diffSets() {
   [[ -n $2 && -z $( grep -vxFf <(echo "${1// /$'\n'}") <(echo "${2//|/$'\n'}") ) ]]
}
```

This function first replaces all spaces with newlines in first set and replaces all pipes with newlines in second set. Then it uses process substitution with `grep -vxFf` to get not-matching text from second set using first set as search patterns.

**Testing:**

```bash
keyword='CAP|BALL|BAT|CRICKET'
s="HE AS CAP AND LOVE TO PLAY BALL BAT , ITS IS CALLED CRICKET"

diffSets "$s" "$keyword" && echo "all" || echo "not all"
all

keywork='CAP|BALL|BAT|CRICKET|FOO'
diffSets "$s" "$keywork" && echo "all" || echo "not all"
not all

diffSets "$s" "" && echo "all" || echo "not all"
not all
```